# Map F2 to replace the 2 key – also with Shift and Alt combination – in Lubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, openbox, xkb, lubuntu

I run a Danish keyboard layout in Lubuntu 14.04.3. The <kbd>2</kbd> key is malfunctioning (hardware problem). I wish to replace its use by the key <kbd>F2</kbd>. The <kbd>F2</kbd> key value (i.e., the <kbd>F2</kbd> key-press event) will then cease to be available.

This way, the result I need will do as follows:

```
Pressed key(s) -> Resulting character

F2             ->          2
Shift + F2     ->          "
Alt + F2       ->          @
```

I am not adequately proficient in Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Linux in general, and despite learning a moderate, but not sufficient, amount of `xmodmap`, `xkb`, `obkey` and `openbox`, along the way, I have not been able to remap <kbd>F2</kbd> as a replacement for the <kbd>2</kbd> key in Lubuntu for my keyboard. How can I do this?

Comment: You need xmodmap. Here - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xmodmap - is everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to modify keymaps, but probably the easiest is to use `xmodmap` utility. First you need a keycode of the <kbd>F2</kbd> key. To get it run `xev`, hit <kbd>F2</kbd> and look for `keycode xx` line. The example output (`68` is important here):

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x7e, subw 0x0, time 373092759, (154,220), root:(162,228),
    state 0x0, keycode 68 (keysym 0xffbf, F2), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0x7e, subw 0x0, time 373092866, (154,220), root:(162,228),
    state 0x0, keycode 68 (keysym 0xffbf, F2), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Now you are ready to modify behavior of this key with `xmodmap`, the syntax is the following:

```
keycode [num] = [bare key] [shift] [Mode_switch] [Mode_switch+shift] [ISO_Level3_Shift] [ISO_Level3_Shift+shift] [Mode_switch+ISO_Level3_Shift] [Mode_switch+ISO_Level3_Shift+shift]
```

That's the theory, in practice the last group very often doesn't do what one would expect. Your demand doesn't seem too difficult, so the following should work:

```
keycode 68 = 2 quotedbl at F2 at F2 F2 F2
```

Comment: Can you also provide the instructions for doing this via XKB? Thanks in advance.